# Advanced Silicon CoolTouch USB touchscreen not working with Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, linux, multi-touch

I'm working with a BSP from Congatech which uses a Freescale Linux kernel (linux-2.6-imx). The touchscreen comes from Fortrend, but it reports itself as an Advanced Silicon CoolTouch (Vendor ID 0x2619, Device ID 0x5610).

What does work:

When you plug the touchscreen into a USB port, the usbhid driver is connecting it to the Linux event system. I can see the device listed in /proc/sys/input/devices and getevent shows me the events it supports and I can monitor live events from it.

However, the touchscreen has no effect on the Android interface at all (for example running the pointer location tool).

In my extensive google searching I've come across some solutions, none of which works. For example it is suggested that the device needs to be handled by the hid-multitouch driver.

What I did was to add this device to the hid_device_id list using MT_CLS_DEFAULT. I also modified the hid-multitouch driver so that it prints during driver init and probe functions. The probe function is never called.

I found more information suggesting that the usbhid driver needs to ignore that device for the hid-multitouch driver to see it. So I've built both drivers to be modules which lets me start the drivers like so:

```
insmod /system/lib/modules/usbhid.ko quirks=0x2619:0x5610:0x4
insmod /system/lib/modules/hid-multitouch.ko
```

The usbhid driver does now ignore the touchscreen when you plug it in, but again the hid-multitouch driver's probe function is not called.

I've quadruple-checked that the vendor ID and device ID are correct in my hid-multitouch driver changes.

```
// hid-ids.h
#define USB_VENDOR_ID_ADVANCEDSILICONSA 0x2619
#define USB_DEVICE_ID_ADVANCEDSILICONSA_5610 0x5610

// hid-multitouch.c
/* Advanced Silicon panels */
{ .driver_data = MT_CLS_DEFAULT,
    HID_USB_DEVICE(USB_VENDOR_ID_ADVANCEDSILICONSA,
    USB_DEVICE_ID_ADVANCEDSILICONSA_5610) },
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me is it a Multi Touch Screen or Just a touch pad?
If it's just a touch pad it must be handled with hid-input.c so there you may want to check if the events are processed. And some dmesg (debug messages) up on connection of your Touchscreen would be good to have here.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. I've passed this problem on to someone else (the guys writing the Android software). My responsibility ended with getting Android built and running on the hardware. I figure they will have more Android knowledge then I'll ever need.